# VBA Outlook userform prompt

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I have a userform that is prompted when I send emails (works great. not the problem) and from there when I click the buttons on the form it moves that email to the respective folder.

What I now want is for that same userform (rather, a duplicate) to be prompted when a message in my inbox goes from unread to read. The buttons on the userform would then move that message to the respective folder.

Code to bring up userform when sending emails:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, cancel As Boolean)

     UserForm1.Show vbModal
   cancel = False
```

End Sub

Code snippet for a button of the userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo error_movemessage

Dim myolapp As New Outlook.Application
Dim mynamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myinbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim mydestfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim myitems As Outlook.Items
Dim myItem As Object

Set mynamespace = myolapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myinbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders("RetainPermanently")
Set myitems = myinbox.Items
Set mydestfolder = myinbox
Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

myItem.Move mydestfolder
Unload Me

exit_CommandButton1_Click:
Exit Sub
error_movemessage:
MsgBox "ERROR! " & Err.Description
Resume exit_CommandButton1_Click

End Sub
```

I searched far and wide for pieces to this puzzle and ultimately ended up unsuccessful. Thank you in advance!

Update:

```
Private Sub getselecteditem_click()

Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim oExp As Outlook.Explorer
Dim oSel As Outlook.Selection
Dim oItem As Object

    Set oExp = oApp.Application
    Set oSel = oExp.Selection

        For i = 1 To oSel.Count

            Set oItem = oSel.Item(i)
                If oItem.Class = olMail Then
                End If
         Next i

End Sub

Sub oItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
    Select Case Name
    Case "UnRead"
        If oItem.UnRead = False Then
        UserForm2.Show vbModal
        End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

Still doesn't work however.

I realized that I've been making this much harder than it needs to be. I can simply get it to pull up the prompt whenever i load a mailitem that happens to be unread. Here is an update:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemLoad(ByVal Item As Object)
    If Item.Class = olMail Then
        If Item.UnRead Then
            UserForm2.Show vbModal
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, if you move an item to a different folder when the message is sent, you are asking for trouble - if you want the message to be saved in a folder other than Sent Items, set the MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder property.

To move a message when its read state changes, track the Explorer.SelectionChange event. When SelectionChange event fires, start tracking the events on multiple messages from the Explorer.Selection collection (there can be more than one, but you can get away with just the first one as a proof of concept). When MailItem.PropertyChange event fires on the Unread property, display your prompt and move the message.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry. How exactly can i go about prompting the userform whenever i want to send a message though?

Comment: Trap the MailItem.Send event. Or Application.ItemSendevent  the way you do it now.

Comment: Ah, thanks again. I failed to truly digest what you were saying was problematic in your first paragraph. Its fixed now.

Comment: Ah, now I'm encountering further difficulties with getting it to work for the inbox whenever a mailitem's property changes from unread to read. Forgive me, my vba coding isn't all that good.

Comment: I know that my code in here is simply asking if the mailitem is read and not tracking the change in property. That's where i wasn't sure how to approach (how to track each mailitem specifically and invoke the userform to move it when the mailitem becomes read). You've done an excellent job to assist with the logic, but I lack syntax knowledge as well to get me to the final result.

Comment: I'm not too sure you can see the code i just put in. Yes, it was outlook VBA. I don't see my comment anymore though.